# как заменить повторяющиеся символы

Tags: c#

К примеру юзер вводит "esyyy hgrrk", а заменить нужно на подобный формат:"esy2 hgr1k". Я предпринимал попытки вводимый текст в string форматировать в char array, а уже в нём проводить итерации с помощью цикла for, в котором происходила проверка: если прошлыйСимвол == настоящийСимвол, то число итератора присваивалось в целочисленный массив как позиция повторяющегося символа. Но так не работает. Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать замену символа на цифру?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] tmparr = new char[textBox1.Text.Length];
    int[] tmpp = new int[5];
    tmparr = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 2; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        char prev = tmparr[i - 1];
        if (tmparr[i] == prev)
        {
            tmpp[j] = i;
            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }
    textBox2.Text = String.Concat<int>(tmpp);
}
```

Comment: @aepot можно использовать всё что пожелает Ваша душа, в этом случае имеется большой простор для полёта мысли :-)

Comment: Тут достаточно одной коллекции (или того, что соберет строку по новой) и некий счетчик, который в случае повторения будет вести отсчет. Примерно, [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DF4bZU). Так что вы намудрили тут с массивами как по мне)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто еще один вариант в копилку

```
var str = "esyyy hgrrk";
var start = 0;
var sb = new StringBuilder();

while(start < str.Length)
{
    var end = start; 
    while(end < str.Length && str[end] == str[start]) end++;
    int count = end - start;        
    sb.Append(str[start]);
    if (count > 1) sb.Append(count-1);
    start = end;        
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать с помощью `StringBuilder`

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int repeatCounter = 0;
    char lastChar = default(char);
    foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
    {
        if (lastChar == c)
            repeatCounter++;
        else
        {
            if (repeatCounter > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(repeatCounter);
                repeatCounter = 0;
            }
            sb.Append(c);
            lastChar = c;
        }
    }
    textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Сломается на такой строке `new string(new char[] {default(char)})`

Comment: @tym32167 знаю, ну а что поделать. Я не думаю, что в условии ожидаются непечатаемые символы в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться этим кодом:

```
var testString = "qjjjjfeeeefqpvnrrr";
char[] charArray = testString.ToCharArray();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(charArray[i]);

    int j = 1;
    while (i + j< charArray.Length && charArray[i] == charArray[i + j])
    {
        j++;
    }
    if (j > 1)
    {
        sb.Append(j.ToString());
        i = i + j - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понял зачем инкрементировать итератор в цикле. Тип такого можно использовать.

string repeatChars = "ddeeeeccciiiiiiiisioooon";
string noRepeatChars = repeatChars[0].ToString();

```
  for (int i = 1; i < repeatChars.Length; i++)
    if (repeatChars[i] == repeatChars[i - 1])
      continue;
    else
      noRepeatChars += repeatChars[i];

  Console.WriteLine($"Было: {repeatChars} \r\nСтало:{noRepeatChars}");
```

Comment: ваш алгоритм просто убрал повторения, но не указал количество повторений. Также сложение строк линейная операция, поглядите в сторону StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Не самый изящный Linq вариант :)

```
var str = "esyyy hgrrk";

var ret = str.Aggregate(new Stack<(char c, int count)>(), (s, c) => {
    if (s.Count == 0 || s.Peek().c!=c) s.Push((c,1));
    else s.Push((c, s.Pop().count+1));
    return s;
})
.Reverse()  
.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s, pair) => {
    s.Append(pair.c);
    if (pair.count > 1) s.Append(pair.count-1);
    return s;
});

Console.WriteLine(ret.ToString());
```

Comment: Быть может оба варианта лучше в один ответ?

Comment: @aepot ответы не связаны между собой, смысл их объединять?

Comment: Это ответы на один и тот же вопрос? Смысл их разделять? Можно просто аккуратно это сверстать в один красивый ответ. К примеру, если бы у меня было 5 разных вариантов решения задачи, мне надо было бы 5 ответов постить?

Comment: @aepot Ну это зависит. Например, если в своем ответе вы хотите показать разнообрание решений и это ваша цель - то вы можете все решения в одном ответе указать. Но если вы просто зотите предложить несколько вариантов решения задачи - то с точки зрения целостности БД каждый самодостаточный ответ должен лежать отдельно - мне кажется в этом есть смысл.

Comment: @aepot сами подумайте, с точки зрения БД вопросов и ответов, является ли важным тот факт, что 2 не связанных ответа на вопрос будут от одного автора или от разных авторов?

Comment: С точки зрения гуглящего - все равно. С точки зрения репы - можно побольше нафармить. С точки зрения чтения ответов как вот я сейчас - удобнее когда их меньше. Ну вам виднее.

Comment: @aepot ну, за репой мне уже поздно гнаться, я просто люблю порядок. Но если вас лично этот ответ сильно беспокоит, я могу его смерджить :)

Comment: А как по мне, то смысл разделять есть. Дело в том, что каждый сможет проголосовать за нужный алгоритм отдельно, а не ставить оценку в целом всей куче вариаций. Это значит что конечный пользователь сможет как минимум по оценкам быстрее сориентироваться куда ему смотреть. В даном случае не вижу ничего зазорного в том что ответ разбит на 2 ответа между собой не связанных.

Comment: @Andrew что и произошло. Итеративный ответ получил +2, linq ответ ладно хоть минусов не нахватал :)

Comment: думаю что для даной задачи итеративный подход лучше. Он и читабельнее выглядит и быстрее должен сработать. Но для "истории" хорошо иметь и его в запасе)

Comment: @Andrew я согласен, хоть и асимптотика у linq и итеративного одинаковая, linq съест больше памяти (на стек) и будет чуть дольше работать. Я вообще linq вариант чисто по приколу написал, такие конструкции в коде не стоит держать, когда можно написать то же самое, но более простыми выражениями.